# how to handle command line input options in python?

Tags: python

I need a script which can take input via command line. Input will be a file name and It will take a default input if no input is provided. The script will also check the existence of the file.

Name of the script is : **wrapper.py**

input example :

```
python wrapper.py -config abc.txt
```

my try:

```
import argparse
commandLineArgumentParser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
commandLineArgumentParser.add_argument("-config", "--configfile", help="first Name")
config = commandLineArguments.configfile
```

Comment: Use getopt its a standard library package for your requirement.

Comment: @Prashant There is nothing wrong with argparse, which Arijit is already using.

Comment: @Arijit Which part causes you trouble? How to get config file from input and have default value? Or how to pass a variable to ConfigParser?

Comment: @zvone my bad I just went through first half of the qns.

Comment: @zvone - Thanks for giving your valuable time . As you can see in config_parser.config file, I have provided the  name of config file. I want to make that part dynamic.

Comment: @PrashantShukla - Thanks for your reply. As zvone said  I am already using argparse package

Comment: Well, I guess you want to put all of it in a function, something like `def load_configuration(filename)`, and in the function, you do `configuration = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()`, `configuration.read(filename)`. Was that your question?

Comment: @zvone - thanks for your valuable reply. Yes , I would like to use a function to call configuration file. As you can see , there are lot of variables present in the configuration file. To receive those variable what will be the best way to do.

Answer (score 0):

You should put you code which loads configuration into a function. Then you should pass file name to it and return all configuration data.

So, start with:

```
def read_configuration_from_file(filename):
    config_parser = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
    config_parser.read(filename)
```

Once you read information from config_parser, you have to figure out how to return the configuration. There are many options. You could return a dictionary, or you could create your own object which contains configuration.

Option 1 (dictionary):

```
return {'first_name': first_name, 'last_name': last_name}
```

Option 2 (configuration data class):

```
class ConfigurationData(object):
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
```

and then you just `return ConfigurationData(first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name)`.

You can also merge it all and make the *read* function part of the class:

```
class ConfigurationData(object):
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name

    @staticmethod
    def read_configuration_from_file(filename):
        config_parser = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
        config_parser.read(filename)
        ...
        return ConfigurationData(first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name)
```